# If dimension of two subspaces are equal then there exists a subspace who direct sum with each of the two is equal to whole space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, direct-sum

> If $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two subspaces of finite-dimensional vector space $V$ such that
>   $\dim(V_1)=\dim(V_2)$, then there exists a subspace $W$ such that  $V1⊕W=V2⊕W=V$

I really don't how to prove this result. All I know is complimentary subspaces are not necessarily unique and that if dimension of two vector spaces are equal, then they are isomorphic. But how to construct $W$ for arbitrary subspaces. Please help.

Comment: Is there any more information about the problem? For example, if $W=V$ then this holds but it seems rather trivial.

Comment: @Cbjork No. This is it.

Comment: @Cbjork You don't get a direct sum when $W=V$.

Comment: In such a case, always think of easy examples. Let $V$ be two-dimensional and $V_1$ and $V_2$ two lines through the origin. You would then choose $W$ to be another line, that merely intersects the other two line at the origin. Now generalize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dim(V_1)=\dim(V_2)=m$ and $\dim(V_1\cap V_2)=r$. We can extend a basis
of $V_1\cap V_2$ to a basis of $V_1$ and to a basis of $V_2$. So there are bases
$v_1,\ldots,v_r,v_{r+1},\ldots,v_m$ of $V_1$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_r,v_{r+1}',\ldots,v_m'$ of $V_2$. Let $w_k=v_k+v_k'$ for $r+1\le k\le m$. Then the span $W$ of $w_{r+1},\ldots,w_m$
has $V_1+V_2=V_1\oplus W=V_2\oplus W$.

This is fine if $V_1+V_2=V$. Otherwise add a complement of $V_1+V_2$ in $V$
to $W$.